# Testing with fake IDbContextFactory injecting data during tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, xunit

I'm using the EFCore 6.0.16 InMemory database provider to set up some tests, but I am encountering null reference issues when performing `context.SaveChanges()` on the scoped context after trying to add to a table.

There's a xUnit fixture for helping in create the database provider for each test class and that holds the method to invoke my fake implementation of a IDbContextFactory for my db context using the `InMemoryDatabase`.

```
public class FakeDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    private readonly DbContextOptions<MyContext> _options;

    public FakeDbContextFactory(string name = "FakeTests")
    {
        _options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<IPSContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(name)
            .Options;
    }

    public MyContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        return new MyContext(_options);
    }

    public Task<MyContext> CreateDbContextAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new MyContext(_options));
    }
}

public class MyFixture : IDisposable
{
    public MyFixture()
    {
    }

    public IDbContextFactory<MyContext> CreateFakeDbContext(string databaseName)
    {
        return new FakeDbContextFactory(databaseName);
    }
}
```

My test signs xml, returns a hashed value and compares it to a pre-determined value written into a table, but this example is a simplified form of that. I want to check that the signed hash is equal to the value inserted into the in memory provider is equal to the computed value.

```
public class HelperTests
{
    private readonly MyFixture  _fixture;
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<MyContext> _fakeDbContextFactory;

    public SignatureHelperTests(MyFixture fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
        _fakeDbContextFactory = _fixture.CreateFakeDbContext(nameof(HelperTests));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test_1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var table = new MyTable
        {
            CreationDateTime = DateTime.Now,
            Id = "1234",
            SignedHash = "HashValue"
        };
    
        using (var context = _fakeDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            context.MyTables.Add(table);
            context.SaveChanges(); // Error is thrown here
   
            // Act
            var sut = new MyHelper(_fakeDbContextFactory);

            var signature = sut.GetValue("<xml>");

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(context.MyTables.Single().SignedHash, signature.SignedHash);
        }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace is below:

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack Trace: 
You may need to build and run this test to see links to source files in the stack trace.
lambda_method304(Closure , String )
<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.<SanitizeConverter>b__1(Object v)
InMemoryTable`1.SnapshotValue(IProperty property, ValueComparer comparer, IUpdateEntry entry)
InMemoryTable`1.Create(IUpdateEntry entry)
InMemoryStore.ExecuteTransaction(IList`1 entries, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 updateLogger)
InMemoryDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
<>c.<SaveChanges>b__104_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)
NonRetryingExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
DbContext.SaveChanges()
```

I originally had the Act and Assert sections outside of the `using` statement figuring the context was disposed but realized it shouldn't matter because my fake returns a new context each time and the fixture should return a new factory and in memory provider per test.

Answer (score 0):

In your CreateDbContext, ensure the database is created:

```
public MyContext CreateDbContext()
{
    var context = new MyContext(_options);
    context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    return context;
}
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#inmemory-provider

Note that the in-memory database is arguably the worst choice to use for unit testing. SQLLite is a better choice, but can still be problematic. Generally the best option for testing is to use a repository pattern (not a Generic Repository) as a mocking boundary for unit tests. This mocks the repository calls, not the DbContext or in-memory linked DbContext.

The issue with the in-memory database is that it will not replicate much of the behavior of an actual database, which can lead to errors or different results/behavior compared to an actual database. SQLLite does behave like a database, however it still does represent a different provider with different behavior from your actual selected database provider.